# Missing a notification for a trashed/deleted file

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using push notifications to watch changes. When I add or update a file everything is ok.

When I delete a file (i.e. it goes to bin) then I do get a notification for that file lets say changeid=81477. When I go to get that change I find that it no longer exists so I can't work out what changed. However if I then go and look at changes I can see a change id=81478 that I never received a notification for. Looking at this change I can see that explicityTrashed = true, which is indicates this is related to the deleted file.

Now, my guess is that change 81477 was superceded by 81478 for some reason, but why do I not receive a notification for 81478?

Someone (non-google) on google+ suggested keeping a track of last change processed and grabbing all changes greater than that when a notification arrives, but this is a workaround to me.

The problem I have is not getting one of the notifications at all. I am posting here in the hope that someone from Google can answer this satisfactorily. 
Is it a bug? Or is it expected?

Should we not rely on getting all changes from notifications and implement something similar to suggested?

Comment: Hi there. I'm having the exactly same problem. The solution that was proposed to you on Google+ seems very hackish. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I didn't manage to find a satisfactory solution. The solution on Google+ is, I agree, more of a workaround than a solution. To me it is clearly a bug on the google side but they don't seem that bothered by it.